# Why does the whole page do postback and RadioButton loses its value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I want a selection from a radio button to run a query to populate a DropDownList. I do not want the whole page to do a postback. My whole page is posting back.

Also, when I copy this page to a test page, the value of the radio button is lost. I need the radio button to drive they query which populates the dropdown.

What am I doing wrong which is causing a full postback?

(The method "**FillAppointmentTypes_SelectedIndexChanged**" is never executed.)

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelToggle" runat="server">

  <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="radDoctors" class="col-md-3 control-label">
        Choose your doctor: <span id="asdf"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radDoctors" runat="server" CssClass="" 
          OnSelectedIndexChanged="FillAppointmentTypes_SelectedIndexChanged"
          AutoPostBack="True">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ddAppointmentTypes" class="col-md-3 control-label">
        Reason for Visit: <span id="Span1"></span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddAppointmentTypes" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have tried a trigger inside the updatedatePanel and outside the content template, no love:

```
<Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="radDoctors" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: Have you tried assigning a trigger e.g `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="" EventName="" />`

Comment: HI there, yes I have.. no luck. i have updated my question.

Comment: Unless I'm going mad everything looks correct. Is there anymore relevant code that is perhaps modifying properties of the update panel or radiobuttonlist in the code behind file?  Also, I would like to point out though that as long as your control triggering the postback is a child of the update panel and ChildAsTrigger is set to true, which it is by default, then you do not need to add the AsyncPostBackTrigger to the Triggers section.

Comment: I'm using jQuery and bootstrap. those are for presentation but they might be causing the issue. Also, this is a template using a masterpage. But that's pretty standard stuff. I had read that one doesn't need an asyncpostback trigger in this case because everything and only the controld in the contenttemplate posts postback by default. But, i'm starting to pull out my hair and try everything I can think of.

Comment: The radiobutton list is populated when the form loads via:
    If (!Page.IsPostBack)
      { LoadRadiobuttonlist() }

Comment: My goal is: a user clicks a radio button and the values of a dropdown change. I have just read that updatePanels are useless, "UpdatePanels always force the entire page to refresh. If you want only a certain portion of the page to be processed (and it's a fixed size) then you could try using an iframe. Alternatively, if you want to save the variables you can either put them in ViewState or SessionState so that they are persisted between postbacks" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099330/c-sharp-updatepanel-with-timer-page-load

Answer (score 0):

Put...

```
if(page.ispostback) 
{
return;
}
```

At the top of your page load event..

Hope this helps

Also maybe set the ChildAsTrigger="true" on the updatepanel

Comment: If the page is not a postback, I prefill the page with queried values. If the page is a postback, I save the content and then redirect the user to a, "you have been updated" type page.

Comment: Sorry for the useless answer. And setting the ChildAsTrigger attribute to true on the update panel was of no use also?

Comment: tried that as well. no luck. the form is still posting a full postback.